# Perl WWW::Mechanize cookie problem

Tags: perl, cookies, captcha, mechanize

I am trying to automate the collection of links from a site that asks for a captcha first.
For this, I capture the captcha image so it can be solved externally, and then submit the solution as part of the form fields.
Somehow it doesn't work. I suspect a cookie problem but I'm not sure and would appreciate if anyone could figure this out.

Here is the code. First I create the mech object along with its cookie jar:

```
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
$agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookie_jar);
$agent->get("http://www.site.com/page.html");
```

I find the link of interest:

```
$link = $agent->find_link(tag => "a", text_regex => qr{regex});
$url = $link->url;
$agent->get($url);
```

At this stage the site presents a captcha. I extract the image and save it so it can be solved by a human, which then enter the solution to continue:

```
$captcha = $agent->find_image(url_regex => qr{captcha\.php});
$agent->get($captcha->url, ':content_file' => 'captcha.jpg');
print "Please solve captcha at http://my.own.site/captcha.jpg\n";
$agent->back;
print "Enter answer: ";
$solved = <>;
```

Now that the script has the captcha solution entered manually, it can continue by submitting the form:

```
$agent->form_with_fields('code');
$agent->set_fields(code => $solved, action => 'download');
$agent->submit;
```

However this doesn't work. The result is the page asking the captcha again, rather than the expected page with the info I'm after.

I am wondering if the cookie gets lost/reset when I do the $agent->back after saving the captcha image?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a much easier way to handle this problem. Here it is:

1. Visit the site with a web browser
2. Solve the captcha
3. Open the cookie generated and note the sessionid
4. Then in the script, set the cookie with that sessionid

Works like a charm.

```
$phpsessid = '4d93c8f247b49780';
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
$agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookie_jar);
$agent->get($url);
$cookie_jar->clear;
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(undef, "SESSIONID", $sessionid, "/", $domain, undef, 1, 0, undef, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is highly possible that the site you are accessing has got some means to detect and hinders free surfing; that means, for example, going back one or more page and then forward again. This is usually done by associating to each page a unique id, so that when you submit the id twice, it is clear that you surfed back and then moved on again from there. As you say, this is related to using `back`.

What I wonder is if you really need going `back`. The key is doing the downloading of the image *outside* of the agent, so that the agent state does not get modified. You could use a second agent for that or `curl`, since you have the direct URL to the image...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't they would use a unique id though, but will verify. However the image url is dynamic (captcha.php) so getting it outside wouldn't work.